# Como comparar si un valor es mayor que otro

Tags: php

Tengo una valor que es 1,485.69 y tengo que hacer una comprobacion si es mayor que 100 hago un cosa o otra pero siempre me dice que es menor, he intentando a pasarlo a entero pero me devuelve 1 que es el que va delante de la , y pasarlo a float pero sigue fallando.

```
 if ($porcentajetarea >=100){
       $porcentajetarea2 = 100;
       echo '1';
 }
 else
 {
       echo '2';
       $porcentajetarea2 = $porcentajetarea;
 }
```

$porcentajetarea es el que almacena el 1,485.69

Comment: porcentajetarea contiene el literal "1,485.69" ? es decir, con la coma y el punto? si es asi, realmente tienes una cadena de caracteres, no un numero, y te puede dar esa comparacion erronea... si lo que quieres es que sea numero, no debe tener la coma.

Comment: Si tiene ambas la , y el punto

Comment: pues ahi tienes el problema. Lo que tienes es una cadena de caracteres, no un numero. Quitale la ,

Answer (score 1):

El contenido de `$porcentajetarea` no sigue el formato de un número.

Si tratas de darle ese valor como número a una variable, te va a arrojar una excepción el sistema.

```
$porcentajetarea = 1,485.69;
```

Esto arrojaría la siguiente excepción:

> FATAL ERROR syntax error, unexpected ',' on line number x

Por esto intuyo que lo que tienes almacenado en `$porcentajetarea` se trata de un `string`:

```
$porcentajetarea = '1,485.69';
```

**¿Por qué entonces puedo compararlo con 100 y que el resultado me arroje además que es menor que dicho número?** Esto sucede porque para poder hacer la comparación **PHP** hace una conversión implícita de `string` a un número con el que poder realizarla y al ser este un formato de número que no sabe interpretar (dado que en programación la coma no es válida para un formato numérico y si el punto para el uso de decimales) te devuelve la parte que si que entiende, que es lo de antes de la coma, un 1.

Para poder ver este proceso interno nos basta con hacer:

```
$numero = '1,485.69';
echo $numero + 0;
```

Aquí estamos forzando una conversión implícita a número de un `string`, como en el caso de compararlo con 100, y vemos que nos devuelve un 1 además de un **Notice** por consola avisándonos de que la conversión, aunque se ha realizado, no ha sido la correcta debido al formato de número utilizado.

> NOTICE A non well formed numeric value encountered on line number x

**Conclusión**

Para poder comparar tu variable y que esta sea mayor que cien, has de tener un número bien formado, similar a:

```
$numero = 1485.69;

if ($numero > 100) {
    echo 'Es mayor';
}
else {
    echo 'Es menor';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**El problema** no es otro que la coma, entonces, si remueves la coma, podrás construir un valor `float` válido y hacer la comparación.

Aquí usaremos `str_replace` para quitar la coma del dato original y la comparación se haría de forma natural.

Asumimos que tu valor existe en forma de cadena (variable `$mData`). También, para simplificar, puedes hacer un ternario con una asignación del mensaje `Es mayor / Es menor` en una variable.

```
$mData="1,485.69";
$mNumber = (float) str_replace(',', '', $mData);
$outPut=$mNumber > 100 ? "Es mayor" : "Es menor";
echo $outPut;
```

**Salida:**

```
Es mayor
```

Si haces una prueba del valor con el que estás trabajando, verás que es un valor numérico válido y por tanto comparable con toda seguridad:

```
var_dump($mNumber);
```

**Salida:**

```
float(1485.69)
```

Answer (score 0):

Una opción (ideal) sería usar la función [`filter_var()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.filter-var.php):

<kbd>**[Ver Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/efc5bbc68b234cf6eb248d10e91a61982b082a63)**</kbd>

```
echo filter_var('1,485.69', FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT, FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_THOUSAND) > 100 ? 'Mayor' : 'Menor';
echo filter_var('1,485.69', FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT, FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_THOUSAND) > 1500 ? 'Mayor' : 'Menor';
```

[FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT](https://www.php.net/manual/es/filter.filters.validate.php)

[FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_THOUSAND](https://www.php.net/manual/es/filter.filters.flags.php)